# Warning: python-2.7.8_2 already installed, it's just not linked

Tags: python, macos

After, I type brew install python

Then I got the error:

Warning: python-2.7.8_2 already installed, it's just not linked

Anyone knows how to fix it? I tried brew link python, it's not working.

Comment: What happened when you tried `brew link python`? Also, what are you expecting? If it's linked, you should get /`usr/local/bin/python2.7` and other `2.7`-suffixed binaries. You can find the un-linked binaries in `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/bin/` to make sure they exist.

Answer (score 3):

I met the same problem and try:

```
brew link --overwrite python
```

it can fix this waring